# Как переписать скрипт с jquery на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Подскажите как написать этот скрипт на простом js.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
//находим теги img и ставим атрибуты    
    $('img').attr({
       "ondrag":"return false",
       "ondragdrop":"return false",
       "ondragstart":"return false"
    })
//выполняем каждые 0,3 сек
}, 300);
```

Comment: [YOU MIGHT NOT NEED JQUERY](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].setAttribute('ondrag', 'return false');
        imgs[i].setAttribute('ondragdrop', 'return false');
        imgs[i].setAttribute('ondragstart', 'return false');
    }
}, 300);
```

Comment: Спасибо, Станислав!